# Could not reduce the size of the Image div - React Js , Tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to Make a clone of the Book My show Application. I'm building the Cast and crew slider. I tried reducing the size of the image but the spacing between the image does not seem to reduce.

This is my js file containing the src, settings for the slider:

```js
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

import CastPoster from "../MovieCast/movieCast.component";

const Cast = (props) => {
 
    const settings = {
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: false,
        speed: 1500,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        InitialSlide: 0,
    }
    
    const CastImages = [
        {
            src:"https://in.bmscdn.com/iedb/artist/images/website/poster/large/simu-liu-2006167-13-05-2021-04-13-21.jpg",
            name:"Simu Liu",
            role:"as Shang-Chi"
        },

        {
            src:"https://in.bmscdn.com/iedb/artist/images/website/poster/large/awkwafina-1093500-20-06-2018-12-05-44.jpg",
            name:"Awkwafina",
            role:"as Katy"
        },

        {
            src:"https://in.bmscdn.com/iedb/artist/images/website/poster/large/tony-leung-iein105711-02-04-2018-13-07-58.jpg",
            name:"Tony Leung Chiu-wai",
            role:"as Wenwu / The Mandarin"
        },

        {
            src:"https://in.bmscdn.com/iedb/artist/images/website/poster/large/michelle-yeoh-1473-24-03-2017-17-32-23.jpg",
            name:"Michelle Yeoh",
            role:"as Jiang Nan"
        }
    ];
    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="">
            <Slider {...settings}>
                {
                    CastImages.map((data) => (
                        <CastPoster {...data} />
                    ))
                }
            </Slider>  
        </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default Cast;
```

This is the js file containing the rendering of the slider:

```js
import React from "react";

const CastPoster = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
        <div className="">
                <img className="rounded-full w-32 h-32 " src={props.src} atl={props.name} />
            <div>
                <h3> {props.name} </h3>
                <p> {props.role} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CastPoster;
```

And I have added it as a component in a page:

```js
import React from "react";
import Cast from "../components/Cast/Cast.component";
import MovieHero from "../components/MovieHero/MovieHero.component";
import offerIcon from "./offericon.png";


const MoviePage = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <MovieHero />
        <div className="my-12 container px-4 lg:w-3/4 lg:ml-20">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-3">
                <h2 className="text-gray-800 font-bold text-2xl"> About the movie </h2>
                <p> Shang-Chi and The Legend of The Ten Rings features Simu Liu as Shang-Chi, who must confront the past he thought he left behind when he is drawn into the web of the mysterious Ten Rings organization. The film is directed by Destin Daniel Cretton and produced by Kevin Feige and Jonathan Schwartz.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="my-8">
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-gray-800 font-bold text-2xl pb-4"> Applicable Offers </h1>
                <div className="flex items-start gap-2 bg-yellow-100 border-yellow-400 border-2 border-dashed rounded-md p-3 w-96">
                    <img className="h-6" src={offerIcon}/>
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
                        <h3 className="relative -top-1 text-gray-900 text-md font-semibold"> Filmy Pass </h3>
                        <p className="text-gray-600 -top-1 text-sm"> Get Rs.75* off on 3 movies you buy/rent on Stream. Buy Filmy Pass @Rs.99 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="my-8">
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3> Cast </h3>
                <div>
                    <Cast />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default MoviePage;
```

The result:
[This is the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXzq2.jpg)

I want to reduce the spacing between the images. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between your images is determined by the amount of slides you want to show and the width of the slider div. To decrease the space between the images reduce the width of the slider or show more images.

Your Cast component could look like this

```
<div className="w-full">
    <Slider {...settings} className="w-1/2">
        {
            CastImages.map((data) => (
                <CastPoster {...data} />
            ))
        }
    </Slider>
</div>
```